# Chart Jumps on drag with d3.zoom d3 v4

Tags: d3.js

I'm using d3 to draw a bunch of arrows (nodes connected by links). I'm using d3.zoom to translate the background when the ctrl key is pressed and the background is clicked on and dragged.

I want to zoom on the arrows so they fill the screen when the page loads. This works fine, but when I pan (by ctrl + drag the background) it jumps from my auto zoomed position to the origin.

(Here I translate by calculating the auto transform/scale, taking child group of the top svg element, and setting its transform attribute)

Here is my code to set up the zoom:

```
zoom(width, height){

 // Get autozoom translate and scale
 const autozoom = this.AutoZoom(width, height);

 // Bind zoom event to top level svg and on zooom append transform attribute to svg > g
 topSvg.call(d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 2])
  .on("zoom", () =>
    svgG.attr("transform", (e) => {
      return d3.event.transform;
    }))
 );

 //Make the initial transform to translate grop
 if ((autozoom != null) ) {
  svg.attr("transform", `translate(${autozoom .translate})scale(${autozoom.scale})`);
 }
}
```

**How do I stop the chart from jumping from translated position to the origin when I click and drag?**

Comment: read the d3-zoom doc, there are functions that does what you want, why use an arrow function if you return something that does not depend on `e`

Comment: Yeah, I've been looking at the documentation. The function translateExtent seems to be what I want to use as I have the top left corner and bottom right corner of the view I want to zoom. I haven't had any success yet. I used an arrow function so I could place breakpoint and test. I forgot to take that out.

Comment: there are more functions with `translate` in the name

Answer (score 1):

After a bunch of digging I found the answer. So there are three things that need to be done when performing an initial zoom on a page with zoom functionality:

1) Calculate the amount needed to translate/scale the svg, then set the transform attribute for the group under the svg.

```
  const groupZoom= this.GetSvgZoom(width, height);
  // svgGroup = svg > g
  svgGroup.attr("transform", `translate(${groupZoom.translate})scale(${groupZoom.scale})`);
```

2) Now that the page has moved, you need to notify the zoom event to start at your translated position.

```
  const extent = this.GetZoomOrigin(width,height);
  d3.zoom().translateTo(svg, extent.translate[0], extent.translate[1]); 
  d3.zoom().scaleTo(svg, extent.scale);
```

3) Finally bind the zoom event to the svg element to give the zoom functionality

```
svg.call(d3.zoom()
  .on("zoom", () =>
    svgGroup.attr("transform", d3.event.transform))
 );
```

Comment: what is  this.GetSvgZoom?

Comment: oh ok, i supposed its a function to retrieve the zoom transforms: var transform = d3.zoomTransform(selection.node());